# QLPreviewController playback video

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I've found strange behaviour on the QLPreviewController modal where Im trying to preview a video and QLPreviewController carries on playing a video after I've dismissed the modal via the "done" button which is provided by default.

Any ideas on why this could be happening or how I can stop the playback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I extended QLPreviewController and in viewWillDisappear i didn't call [super viewWillDisappear] which was causing the video to still playback in the background.